# What language is this? Docusign API

Tags: api, docusignapi

So this may be a dumb question, but I am trying to learn about Docusign's REST API.  Most of the information is in the following format.  I primarily use PHP but am not exactly an expert.  I really like the flow of the code below.  Can someone tell me what language this is (below)?

```
{
"accountId": "12345",
"emailSubject": "DocuSign Signature Request from Template",
"templateId": "44D9E888-3D86-4186-8EE9-7071BC87A0DA",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "email": "sally.doe@email.com",
        "name": "Sally Doe",
        "roleName": "Signer1",
        "tabs": {
            "textTabs": [
                {
                    "tabLabel": "ApplicantName",
                    "value": "Sally Doe"
                },
                {
                    "tabLabel": "ApplicantSSN",
                    "value": "12-345-6789"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
"status": "sent"
```

}

Comment: That's JSON. It's a data format, not a language, and this is not a language-identification (or format-identification) service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [JSON](http://json.org/).

See also Wikipedia:

> [JSON] is an open-standard format that uses human-readable text to transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs. It is the most common data format used for asynchronous browser/server communication (AJAJ), largely replacing XML which is used by AJAX.